# How to run a single TestNG test which has dependencies in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

Is there a way to run a test method which depends on a group in intellij, using the Run dialog, without getting exception  - "depends on nonexistent group "first" "

For Example :

**testOne.java**

```
public class testOne {
    @Test(groups = "first")
    public void testA() {}
}
```

**testTwo.java**

```
public class testTwo {
    @Test (dependsOnGroups = "first")
    public void testB() {}
}
```

If i try to run testB which depends on group first using run dialog in intellij i am getting below exception

> org.testng.TestNGException:  DependencyMap::Method "testTwo()[pri:0,
>   instance:test.tests.test2@6fd02e5]" depends on nonexistent group
>   "first"

Answer (score 0):

As the testB is dependant on testA, you cannot run the testB independently, although you can run testA independently as its execution doesn't depend on any other test.
So, to solve your situation, either you can to remove the dependsOnGroups parameter from testB or you can run both the classes using testng.xml or you can run both the tests by right clicking on the package name where both the classes are located and then run it as testng test.